# jQuery adding days to a date

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a number of days to a date selector input to get a start date and end date. I am getting an incorrect end date and cant see why.

Example: Date selected 25-10-2011, days 1

Result: date_start 2011-9-25, date_end 2012-5-7

```
 function makeUpDates(){
      // concantenate values to date_start and date_end hidden inputs
      var dateString = document.getElementById('date').value,
      date = new Date(dateString);
      document.getElementById('date_start').value = date.getFullYear() + '-' + date.getMonth() + '-' + date.getDate();

      var numDays = document.getElementById('slider').value;
      date.setDate(date.getDate() + numDays);   
      var dateEnd = date.getFullYear() + '-' + date.getMonth() + '-' + date.getDate();
      document.getElementById('date_end').value = dateEnd;
 }
```

Comment: @Keith Power It appears to be working, minus the values you are pulling from the controls. http://jsfiddle.net/fTcBQ/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the numDays had to be converted to an integer before added. Otherwise I was getting strange results.

```
function makeUpDates(){
      // concantenate values to date_start and date_end hidden inputs
      var dateString = document.getElementById('date').value,
      date = new Date(dateString);
      alert (date);
      document.getElementById('date_start').value = date.getFullYear() + '-' + (date.getMonth()+1) + '-' + date.getDate();

      var numDays = document.getElementById('slider').value;
      date.setDate(date.getDate() + parseInt(numDays)); 

      var dateEnd = date.getFullYear() + '-' + (date.getMonth()+1) + '-' + date.getDate();
      document.getElementById('date_end').value = dateEnd;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

I prefer passing arguments to functions rather than using hidden inputs. I also wanted the date to come out in the original format, since I'm working with date pickers expecting the date string in a particular format. I also decided to make the function a little more flexible with regard to the date separator and padding. Usage: AddDaysToDate("03/18/2016", 5, "/"), adds 5 days so returns "03/23/2016."

```
function AddDaysToDate(sDate, iAddDays, sSeperator) {
    //Purpose: Add the specified number of dates to a given date.
    var date = new Date(sDate);
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + parseInt(iAddDays));
    var sEndDate = LPad(date.getMonth() + 1, 2) + sSeperator + LPad(date.getDate(), 2) + sSeperator + date.getFullYear();
    return sEndDate;
}
function LPad(sValue, iPadBy) {
    sValue = sValue.toString();
    return sValue.length < iPadBy ? LPad("0" + sValue, iPadBy) : sValue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  var today       =new Date('12/22/1978');
 var in_a_day   =new Date(today).setDate(today.getDate()+1); //+1 or +x
```

edit your date format should be : `mm/dd/yyyy`

Comment: -1 OP is already doing this, date.setDate(date.getDate() + numDays);

Comment: @Aaron McIver - he's problem is in the building the date object. not in the setDate sentence...

Comment: I my check the format of the date var it is Tue Oct 25 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time), how would I format at the same time as add on date.setDate(date.getDate() + numDays); ?

Comment: @Keith Power , in your screen yo see format as `25-10-2011` ?

Comment: sorry that should say 10/25/2011 not 25/10/2011

Comment: so whats the problem  - ensemble the date via 10+/+25+/+2011 into the constructor of my fund :)

Comment: I did not to format before, here is an example and it works fine http://jsfiddle.net/ukkpower/Qy5hp/

Comment: The issue is with numDays, if I alert the value in the jQuery slider I get 1, but I get the date issue. If I just put 1 in myself I get the correct date, does anyone know why?

Comment: @Keith Power Have checked numDays? What is it resolving to?

Comment: Hey Aaron, what I did was use parseInt(numDays) to make sure it was a integer I was adding. Thanks